# Factory method example in spark-shell giving error

Tags: scala, design-patterns, apache-spark, factory-method

I am unable to run below code in spark-shell repl. This is a reproduction from [Scala cookbook example provided by Alvin Alexander](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/factory-pattern-in-scala-design-patterns)
I get the error:

```
<console>:22: error: reference to Animal is ambiguous;
it is imported twice in the same scope by
import $VAL11.Animal
and import INSTANCE.Animal
       val test = Animal("dog")
```

This works fine with Scala repl. Can you please tell me how I can make this example work on spark-shell as well?

Thanks a lot for your help!

```
trait Animal {
    def speak
}
object Animal {
    private class Dog extends Animal {
        override def speak = {
            println("woof")
        }
    }

    private class Cat extends Animal {
        override def speak { println("meow") }
    }
    def apply(s: String):Animal = {
        if (s == "dog") return new Dog
        else return new Cat
    }

}


# repl
Animal("dog") 

# compiling
object test {
    def main(args: Array[String]){
        Animal(args(0)).speak
    }
}
```

Comment: Use  `:paste` command so `Animal` companions are compiled together. Is that your question?

Comment: Thanks @som-snytt. I use :paste. After your comment, I realized I was running these in spark-shell and not scala repl. I will change my question.

Comment: Probably https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9740. If you try `Animal("pug") // show` it may show what is imported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As som-snytt pointed out, this is most likely [a version of an existing scala bug.](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9740)

```
Animal("dog") // show
```

results in something like this:

```
import $line15.$read.INSTANCE.$iw.$iw.Animal;
val $line15$read = $line15.$read.INSTANCE;
import $line15$read.$iw.$iw.Animal;
```

Note that `Animal` is imported twice. To fix this you can wrap your code in an `object`:

```
object test{
  trait Animal {
    def speak
  } 

  object Animal {
    private class Dog extends Animal {
      override def speak = {
        println("woof")
      }
    }

    private class Cat extends Animal {
      override def speak { println("meow") }
    }

    def apply(s: String):Animal = {
      if (s == "dog") return new Dog
      else return new Cat
    }
  } 
}
```

Now, when you call `test.Animal("dog") // show` you get this instead:

```
val $line15$read = $line15.$read.INSTANCE;
import $line15$read.$iw.$iw.$iw.$iw.$iw.$iw.$iw.$iw.test;
```

Note that you get only one, more concise import.

As an interesting side note, if you run your first code and then the second, then `test.Animal("dog")` results in this:

```
import $line15.$read.INSTANCE.$iw.$iw.Animal;
val $line16$read = $line16.$read.INSTANCE;
import $line16$read.$iw.$iw.$iw.$iw.$iw.$iw.$iw.$iw.test;
```

Where the `Animal` import remains.